# Geometric Dimensioning and Tolerancing support in EZDXF Python

Tags: python, autocad, cad, dxf, ezdxf

I am trying to read the GD&T Symbols like Concentricity, Perpendicularity using ezdxf parser on DXF Files. The GDT Symbols get read as TOLERANCE Entity and using the content attribute I have succeeded to find the tolerance value, GDT Type and the associated Datum. Is there a way I can find out to which measurement (for ex - Linear dimension), it is associated with ? For ex - In the image below, I am able to understand that there is a Concentricity Symbol, with tolerance 0.02 with Datum. I do  not know what is the other circle being referred to (Concentricity being a feature dependent on two entities, one is the datum and the other unknown). I would want to know that the Concentricity is associated the the linear dimension phi 13.

[image]

You can find the DXF at this location [Sample DXF File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16zP398NDxew1_yCYBdm6tJEXA37f2AL9/view?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is tagged DXF is it not possible for you to share a sample DXF file with such an element?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, are u asking me share a sample DXF File?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.

Comment: Okay, I will upload

Comment: I have added the link for the DXF in the question

Comment: Thanks for sharing your file. I am afraid that it seems I can't provide a solution. I was hoping that your elements had XDATA (extended entity data) which might have had the handles to the linked elements. But they are plain entities. I admit I don't ful;ly understand all the technical terms you mention but can't you just find the smaller circle element that has the same centroid as the outer one? I am afraid I have to bail out on this one. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I will consider your suggestion to mathematically find concentricity. Thanks anyways for the effort.